# mysql fields max length of for each data type

Tags: magento-1.8, mysql, fieldsets

I am checking for maximum length of each data type fields in magento.

For example "Text" field, magento has many text fields by default, so what is the maximum length of the default text fields.
and I also wanted to know these information

**Using trim function or not?
what is default values?**

Similar, I wanted to know all the data type max length.

**Text:**

**Text Area:**

**Email:**

**Password:**

Where I can get all these information?
Can anyone help me to understand all these.?

Thanks in advance for your valuable response